# How to find local git branches that have been deleted from master

Tags: git

In our workflow, development branches which are production-ready get pushed to the remote tracking repository where they are merged into master. The branch is deleted when the tests pass.

I have been bad about deleting my local version of those development branches, so now I have many local branches which don't have a corresponding branch on origin.

Is there a quick way to find which branches in my repository have already been deleted from the remote repository?

Comment: By "local branch", you mean branches under `refs/heads`, and not remote-tracking branches under `refs/remotes/origin`?

Comment: yes, `refs/heads` - which I think of as local, because the global repository doesn't see those changes unless I push.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

#### Finding and deleting local branches under refs/heads

Assuming that the original poster means he wants to delete local branches under `refs/heads` and not remote-tracking branches under `refs/remotes/origin`, then to find branches that have already been merged into `origin/master`, simply use the following:

```bash
# Fetch latest copy of origin/master
$ git fetch origin

# Find merged branches
$ git branch --merged origin/master
```

The output will show you branches which have been merged nto `origin/master`, and are thus safe to delete with `git branch -d <branch>`. From the [official Linux Kernel Git documentation for `git branch`](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-branch.html):

> "--merged" is used to find all branches which can be safely deleted, since those branches are fully contained by HEAD.

#### Deleting remote-tracking branches under refs/remotes/origin

If, on the other hand, the original poster meant that he wanted to delete his remote-tracking branches, then simply pass the `-p` or `--prune` flags to `git fetch`:

```
$ git fetch -p origin
```

From the [official Linux Kernel Git documentation for `git fetch`](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-fetch.html):

> After fetching, remove any remote-tracking branches which no longer exist on the remote.

Answer (score 2):

```
git fetch -p
```

From the manual:

> -p, --prune
>              After fetching, remove any remote-tracking branches which no longer exist on the remote.

Comment: Note that this only removes remote-tracking branches, and will not touch local branches under `refs/heads`.